# Grub2 Iso boot problems

Tags: grub2, live-usb, iso

Again I'm trying to get a working all-purpose USB-Stick with multiple ISO images to boot from. Installation worked fine to be able to boot from EFI and legacy systems as well, but beside the ubuntu-desktop (ubuntu-gnome in this case) all other images stop during boot stating that the CD-Image or root system can not be found.

My menu-entries for grub:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu Gnome" {
  set isofile="/ubuntu-gnome-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
  loopback loop $isofile
  linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi iso-scan/filename=$isofile boot=casper file=(loop)/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed noprompt quiet splash --
  initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}

menuentry "Ubuntu Server" {
  set isofile="/ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso"
  loopback loop $isofile
  linux (loop)/install/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile quiet --
  initrd (loop)/install/initrd.gz
}


menuentry "Gentoo Live" { 
  set isofile="/gentoo-livedvd-amd64-multilib-20160704.iso"
  loopback loop $isofile
  linux (loop)/isolinux/gentoo setkmap=de isoloop=$isofile docache dostartx
  initrd (loop)/isolinux/gentoo.xz 
}

menuentry "Gentoo Install Minimal" { 
  set isofile="/install-amd64-minimal-20170112.iso"
  loopback loop $isofile
  linux (loop)/isolinux/gentoo setkmap=de isoloop=$isofile docache
  initrd (loop)/isolinux/gentoo.igz 
}

menuentry "SystemRescueCD" { 
  set isofile = "/systemrescuecd-x86-4.9.1.iso"
  loopback loop $isofile
  linux (loop)/isolinux/rescue64 setkmap=de isoloop=$isofile docache dostartx
  initrd (loop)/isolinux/initram.igz 
}
```

Gentoo based systems (SysResCD and Gentoo Installer/Live) claim to not find root system, Ubuntu-Server stops installation after selecting the locale stating that not CD can be found.

There are other posts here about this, but all about quite old versions. At least the ubuntu-server.iso has changed quite a bit.

Any hints welcome.

Comment: There are easy to use tools for that like Multisystem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I want to learn, not only use. I want to understand what I'm doing wrong. That won't happen by using a tool that does that for me.

Comment: They change vmlinuz to add then remove .efi and initrd.gz or lz or nothing. I often have to mount ISO and check what details it has in its grub.cfg.